# Internal Server Error Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

estoy obteniendo un internal server error en heroku cuando intento acceder a mi django app solo cuando tengo DEBUG=FALSE, he intentado hacer el collectstatic y tambien añadir el host a los ALLOWED_HOST pero el problema persiste

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que tambien necesitas decir a heroku que estas subiendo, el no sabe yo le configuraste el procfile e instalaste los paquetes que necesita django para heroku?

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]